# My computer has suddenly become unstable, unable to login and screen is patch green on freezes

Tags: linux, boot, bios

my computer has suddenly become unstable. I run ubuntu 10.10 and the computer setup has ran well for ages. However, about 10 minuets ago that computer has become extremely unstable.

I was just about to push some code to the android emulator and this problem happened. The kernel panic is fine, but the computer wouldn't reboot properly and I had to turn the power at the wall off and on again. The BIOS then asked me to setup the computer, as settings had been damaged.

Next, as the computer attempted to boot, I got a stack trace from somewhere after the computer displayed "STARTING ASUS EXPRESS GATE" and said about the unknown root file system wouldn't load.

I rebooted, and the system booted and Ubuntu checked the disks, however about 1-2 minuets after logging in, the computer now freezes with about 50% of the screen randomly covered in green.

Has anybody got any suggestions as to what could be the problem? (I hope i've posted this to the correct site)

Joe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very likely a hardware problem there, possibly motherboard-related. A good easy way to eliminate software as a problem would be to boot from a livecd, and see if you get the same issues.

Comment: Hm... I opened up the computer and had a fiddle with the wires and it seems to be working. Thanks anyway

Comment: Just an update: The problem happened again and I got the motherboard replaced. To anyone who has this: Just replace your motherboard.